# Snakemake: coupling inputs and outputs without shared wildcards

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a set of inputs: [A, B, C, D]

And a set of outputs: [1, 2, 3, 4]

I want the input/output pairs to be: A1, B2, C3, D4 for a rule.

How do I do that in a snakefile?

Answer (score 2):

It would help to gave more details and some example code of your problem. Anyway, I would put the letter/number pairs in a dictionary or dataframe and use a lambda function to access the number corresponding to a letter:

```
numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

ln = dict(zip(numbers, letters))

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{number}.txt', number= numbers),

rule out:
    input:
        letter= lambda wc: ln[wc.number],
    output:
        '{number}.txt'
    shell:
        """
        echo {input.letter} > {output}
        """
```

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly! I adjusted it for my use case, but mapping keys and values as output:input worked like a charm.